# What is known about sums of non-integer zeta values?

Tags: sequences-and-series, reference-request, analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta

There is quite a bit of literature that describes how sums of zeta values at integral arguments can be evaluated, see for instance [1] [2]. On p.7 of [3], however, the author notes that he has not been able to find a closed-form expression for any sum of zeta values at the half-integers.

**Questions**

1. What is known about sums of zeta values at half-integer arguments?
2. Is anything known about sums of zeta values at rational arguments?

**Sources**

[1] *Computational Strategies for the Riemann Zeta Function* -- Borwein, Bradley, Crandall (2000) : [link](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0377042700003368?via%3Dihub).

[2] *Some Series for the Zeta and Related Functions* -- Adamchick and Srivastava (1998) : [link](https://www.degruyter.com/view/j/anly.1998.18.issue-2/anly.1998.18.2.131/anly.1998.18.2.131.xml)

[3] *The Spiral of Theodorus and Sums of Zeta-values at the Half-integers* -- Brink (2012) : [link](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/262855915_The_Spiral_of_Theodorus_and_Sums_of_Zeta-values_at_the_Half-integers)

Comment: By "What is known..." do you mean applications or exact values?

Comment: @SeanNemetz the latter.

Comment: [$\zeta(1/2)$](https://oeis.org/A059750) and [$\zeta(3/2)$](https://oeis.org/A078434)

Comment: @Mason thank you for these links. Just to clarify: I'm looking for results on infinite sums of such values, akin to sums found on this page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_zeta_series (only now the arguments in the Riemann zeta function are not integers)

Comment: Wow!!! What a wonderfull unsolved problem!!! Thank you very much Max!!!

Answer (score 1):

I hope this Lemma will help you

LEMMA. If $f(x)$ have Taylor series around $0$ in $(-a,a)$, $a\geq 1$. If also the Taylor series of $f(x)$ converges absolutely in $x=1$. Then exists constant $C_f$  depending from $f(x)$ such
$$
\sum^{N}_{k=1}f\left(\frac{1}{k}\right)=\int^{N}_{1}f\left(\frac{1}{t}\right)dt+C_f+O\left(N^{-1}\right)\textrm{, }N\rightarrow \infty\tag 1
$$
and
$$
C_f=f(0)+f'(0)\gamma+\sum^{\infty}_{s=2}\frac{f^{(s)}(0)}{s!}\left(\zeta(s)-\frac{1}{s-1}\right).\tag 2
$$
The proof is in pages 36-39 of [link](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/200476182_Numerical_Evaluations_of_Functions_Series_and_Integral_Transforms_with_New_Sampling_Methods).

Setting weights to above formula (1), we get for $0<\alpha<1$
$$
\sum^{N}_{k=1}f\left(\frac{1}{k}\right)\frac{1}{k^{\alpha}}-\int^{N}_{1}f\left(\frac{1}{t}\right)\frac{1}{t^{\alpha}}dt=C_f(\alpha)+O\left(N^{a-1}\right)\textrm{, }N\rightarrow \infty\tag 3
$$
and
$$
C_f(a)=f(0)\left(\zeta(\alpha)-\frac{1}{\alpha-1}\right)+f'(0)\left(\zeta(1+\alpha)-\alpha^{-1}\right)+
$$
$$
+\sum^{\infty}_{s=2}\frac{f^{(s)}(0)}{s!}\left(\zeta(s+\alpha)-\frac{1}{s+\alpha-1}\right).\tag 4
$$
EXAMPLE. With $\alpha=1/2$, $f(t)=\frac{1}{1+\lambda t}$,  $|\lambda|<1$, we get
$$
\sum^{N}_{k=1}\frac{\sqrt{k}}{k+\lambda}=2\lambda^{1/2}-2+2\lambda^{1/2}\textrm{arccot}(\lambda^{1/2})-2\lambda^{1/2}\arctan\left(\frac{N^{1/2}}{\lambda^{1/2}}\right)+\sum^{\infty}_{s=2}(-1)^s\lambda^{s}\left(\zeta(s+1/2)-\frac{1}{s-1/2}\right)+O(N^{-1/2})
$$

Comment: Thank you Nikos!

Comment: You are welcome. If you need details about the proof of (3),(4), I can provide you with some.